# Electron: single instance, replace with new instance

Tags: electron

Docs says how to prevent multiple app versions by quitting the second instance:

```js
const isSingleInstance = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!isSingleInstance) {
    app.quit();
}
```

Is there a way to do the opposite: quit the 1st instance and let the 2nd run?

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so, you can mark an answer as correct by ticking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: I haven't tried it anymore. Maybe the problem is that 1 instance is dev and the other is production? Ended up modifying watch script to kill all instances before running the watch task.

Comment: I don't accept answers if they didn't work for me. Sorry. If anyone else finds your answer working, I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof-of-concept way to do this:

```js
app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

app.on("second-instance", () => {
    /* This event fires in the already-running instance
       and tells you that there's another instance */
    console.log("second instance discovered, quitting!");
    app.quit();
})
```

Comment: Using this code just makes 2 instances running at the same time.

Comment: It works for me in an empty project that I created in order to answer your question. Maybe you can reproduce the solution in an empty project as well. Note that `second-instance` will only fire if `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()` was called.